# Elasticserach query to find document having fields as mising or have some value

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to form a query where if region field is missing or region has value ASIA, list all the document. but its response is empty list if i run the query. How can we form such query?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "region": "ASIA"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "region"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want a [should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in this case

bool --> should --> condition1 , condition2

should = OR, so below will match documents that either meet condition1 OR condition2

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "region": [
              "asia"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "region"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```